# Why is SQL treating my 'after' trigger as an instead of

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have the following trigger:

```
Alter trigger [dbo].[EmployeeLearningNeedsDeleteAuditTrigger]
on [dbo].[EmployeeLearningNeeds]
after delete
...
```

For some reason, SQL Management Studio squiggles this as an error, stating:

> Cannot create INSTEAD OF DELETE trigger [dbo].[EmployeeLearningNeedsDeleteAuditTrigger] on [dbo].[EmployeeLearningNeeds]. This is because table has a FOREIGN KEY with cascading delete.

What I don't understand, is this isn't an 'instead of delete' this is an 'after delete' so why is it throwing up such an error?

Just in case it's relevant I've included the contents of the trigger:

```
as

DECLARE @Count int;
select @Count = @@ROWCOUNT;

set nocount on;

if @Count > 0
begin
            declare @RowId int;
            declare @Value varchar(max);

            select @RowId=RecordId from deleted;

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select RecordId from deleted));
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'RecordId', @Value, '';

            select @Value=RTRIM(surname)+', '+RTRIM(forename1)+' '+RTRIM(forename2) from employee where emp_no=(select EmployeeId from deleted);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'EmployeeName', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select TrainingEventId from deleted));
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'TrainingEventId', @Value, '';

            select @Value=[Description] from TrainingEventPart where RecordId=(select TrainingEventPartId from deleted);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'TrainingEventPart', @Value, '';

            select @Value=NeedDescription from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'NeedDescription', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select TargetDate from deleted), 103);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'TargetDate', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select DateAchieved from deleted), 103);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'DateAchieved', @Value, '';

            select @Value=[Description] from LearningNeedPriority where Code=(select [Priority] from deleted);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Priority', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select RenewableAfter from deleted));
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'RenewableAfter', @Value, '';

            if (select Renewed from deleted)=1
                            select @Value='Yes';
            else
                            select @Value='No';
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Renewed', @Value, '';

            if (select SelfNominated from deleted)=1
                            select @Value='Yes';
            else
                            select @Value='No';
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'SelfNominated', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select DateNominated from deleted), 103);
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'DateNominated', @Value, '';

            if (select Approved from deleted)=1
                            select @Value='Yes';
            else
                            select @Value='No';
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Approved', @Value, '';

            select @Value=ApprovedBy from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'ApprovedBy', @Value, '';

            select @Value=ActionBy from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'ActionBy', @Value, '';

            select @Value=CONVERT(varchar, (select EstimatedCost from deleted));
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'EstimatedCost', @Value, '';

            select @Value=Comment1 from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Comment1', @Value, '';

            select @Value=Comment2 from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Comment2', @Value, '';

            select @Value=Notes from deleted;
            exec wnf_InsertAuditRecord 'D', @RowId, 'EmployeeLearningNeeds', 'Notes', @Value, '';
end
```

Many thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the trigger you're altering isn't *currently* an instead of trigger? If that's not it, I wouldn't worry too much about what IntelliSense "warns" you about - the parsing is not exactly accurate in all cases, especially if SSMS and the server you're running against are not the same version. Come back if you get that error when you actually *execute* it.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - whether a trigger can have this much code like `SP` call's etc..

Comment: It's altering an after trigger, unfortunately. It does seem to execute ok, so I wasn't too worried, but somewhere deep in this SQL there's an issue so I was hoping this was the cause. Perhaps you're right and this was sadly a red herring.

Comment: A few other comments: (1) It's a trigger, not a function. (2) `@Count` will *always* be `1` given your current logic. (3) Your trigger currently assumes that only one row will ever be deleted at a time, or that the trigger fires per row. It fires once per statement, meaning that either you will manipulate some arbitrary row or your statements will just break. (4) Please [don't be lazy about things like `varchar` vs. `varchar(11)` (for ints) or `char(10)` (for dd/mm/yyyy)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: @NoDisplayName sure, why not? It's a trigger, not a function. You can shoot yourself in the foot in many ways.

Comment: I didn't write it, sadly. I'm trying to root out someone else's issues, I've no idea about SQL - I'm the web guy. Always the way.

Comment: Just a word of caution: a trigger should be **very nimble** and do the **absolute minimum** possible. **DO NOT** put extensive processing and time consuming tasks into a trigger! This is really bad design. This trigger of yours looks way too "bulky" and way to "busy" - try to slim it down significantly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Aaron stated in a comment, this was just a red herring in the Intellisense.